# Can't connect to my github repository from netbeans

Tags: github, netbeans

I'm trying to connect to my github repository with netbeans but I get this error 
Cannot connect to repository at https://github.com/dfuvx98/ingSWoct2019.git
I copy the link from github and also put right my username and password. 
I'm trying to clone the repository with htttp

Answer (score 1):

Generate personal access tokens and put the token instead of the password in the password box.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try and clone it from the command-line:

```
git clone https://github.com/dfuvx98/ingSWoct2019
```

Then import the (currently empty) repo into Netbeans.
It would be easier if that repository included a project of some kind.

If you do the clone through NetBeans, make sure to use the HTTPS URL ([not `http://` as it is shown by default](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#clone))

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/clone-wizard.png]

Comment: Thanks and I will try to do what you say. Do I use CMD to input the command you say?

Comment: Yes, a simple cmd, with git added to the path, will be enough

Comment: I did that but even after importing I couldn't clone with netbeans later. With CMD it is possible

Comment: @DiegoUtreras The idea is to clone in CMD, *avoiding* to use NetBeans for cloning. You would use Netbeans only to open a project within the local folder which results from your clone.

Comment: ok then, Can I ask you something different then? This is for a homework and out teacher gave us some code that we need to fix and save the changes we do in Github. How do I link that proyect with the repository?

Comment: @DiegoUtreras If you the code already on GitHub, a clone of that non-empty repository is enough, provided you are the owner or a collaborator of that GitHub repository.

Comment: @DiegoUtreras But if you need to create a new empty GitHub repository, then you can add a remote URL to your local repo (`git remote add origin https://github.com/<you>/newRepo`) and then push to it (from CMD or NetBeans)

Comment: The proyect isn't in Github, I have it in my PC only. Also where the cloned repository from the CMD goes?

Comment: @DiegoUtreras If the project is not yet on GitHub, there is nothing to clone. If you clone a repo, it goes into the folder you specify: `git clone URL afolder`: if you omit `aFolder`, Git will use the repo name as a folder it creates locally.

Comment: @DiegoUtreras If the project is in a local folder, you can do in that project folder a `git init .` + a `git remote add origin https://github.com/you/emptyRepo` + a `git add .; git commit -m "First commit";git push -u origin master`

Comment: How do I add the proyect that I have to the cloned repository to be able to import it to netbeans?

Comment: @DiegoUtreras "to the cloned repository" where do you clone this repository from? Was it from GitHub (I suppose not, since you mentioned the project was not on GitHub yet)

Comment: I did the clone from the empty repository, I have now the folder ingSWoct2019 in my PC. I want the proyect to be in that repository. How I put the proyect in that repository?

Comment: @DiegoUtreras Then add your files in the local folder (where you see a .git subfolder), and `git add .; git commit -m "First commit";git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 0):

If you can reach the repo from your web browser, it could be a proxy issue. Are you behind any firewall? or Are you using any proxy?

If you are behind a proxy, then you may need to provide proxy settings to Netbeans.
see - https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/proxyConfiguration/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, from my web browser I can reach it easily, I have no idea if I'm behind a firewall or using a proxy. I will try to see if I'm behind a proxy as you say.